# How to show full contents of a column in GridView while using Dynamic Pages of ASP .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using list template of dynamic pages. My data from DB model is rendering properly but in some cases where length of data is more than 22 then it shows first 22 characters followed by **...**
[image: Please check first column of second row]

```
<style>
    .gridpadding td {
      padding: 8px;
    }

    .content-wrapper {
      max-width: 1024px;
    }
</style>
<div class="DD">
  <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" EnableClientScript="true"
    HeaderText="List of validation errors" />
  <asp:DynamicValidator runat="server" ID="GridViewValidator" ControlToValidate="GridView1" Display="None" CssClass="DDValidator" />
  <table>
    <tr>
      <asp:QueryableFilterRepeater runat="server" ID="FilterRepeater">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <td style="text-align: left; font-size: 11px;">
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DisplayName") %>' OnPreRender="Label_PreRender" />
            <p style="padding: 6px; margin: 0px;">
              &nbsp;
              <asp:DynamicFilter runat="server" ID="DynamicFilter" OnFilterChanged="DynamicFilter_FilterChanged" />
            </p>
          </td>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:QueryableFilterRepeater>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="GridDataSource" EnablePersistedSelection="true"
  AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
  CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="2" Width="100%" PageSize="25" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
  <HeaderStyle BackColor="#c7d1d6" BorderWidth="1" Font-Bold="True" />
  <RowStyle BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1" CssClass="gridpadding" />
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="&nbsp; Action">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DynamicHyperLink runat="server" Action="Edit" Text="Edit" ID="hlEdit" />
        &nbsp;
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"     ID="hlDelete" OnClientClick='return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?");' />
        &nbsp;
        <%--<asp:DynamicHyperLink runat="server" Text="Details" ID="hlDetails" />--%>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="Password" Text="ChangePassword" ID="hlPassword" />
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="Disable" Text="Disable" ID="hlDisable" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
  <PagerStyle />
  <EmptyDataTemplate>
    There are currently no items in this table.
  </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

I want to show the full content in cell instead of content with **...**

[image: HTML source code as rendered in browser]

Comment: This isn't Classic ASP.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to apply a

```
style="width: 100px"
```

attribute to your `<td>` and make it big enough to display the text that way. obviously 100px is just an example. you can also use percentages like

```
style="width: 70%"
```

if you are still having issues after that try placing a `<div>` tag in your `<td>` and set the width of that

Comment: The columns are bind dynamically so cannot use BoundField.

Comment: @bhushan can you simply add a width attribute to the label its in?

Comment: there are no labels. Its a plain text bind as value displayed in GridView. I have attached snapshot of HTML source code.

Comment: @bhushan ok I see. Can you not just apply a width to the td tag?